# What language does Karum speak?

Tags: dialogue, space-sweepers

What language or dialect does Karum speak in Space Sweepers? It seems to be mostly English, but with something else mixed in.

IMDb [lists](https://imdb.com/title/tt12838766/) the languages in the film as *Russian French Spanish Korean English Japanese Danish Chinese Arabic German Filipino Mandarin*. Karum is voiced by [Bambadjan Bamba](https://imdb.com/name/nm2262926/), who was born in the [Ivory Cost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abidjan) but has lived in various places.

Comment: https://asianwiki.com/Nas_Brown

Comment: @bcdotweb yes, that too. I think he was played by Nas and voiced by Bamadjan?

Comment: So Nas must speak Korean 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on which language version you were watching.

In the English dub version on Netflix in the UK, Karum (voiced by Bambadjan Bamba) speaks plain English with a slightly dodgy Nigerian accent.

However, in the original Korean language version Karum is voiced by the actual actor (Nas Brown) and is speaking in Nigerian Pidgin (a creole language loosely based in English).

However, I can find no official confirmation of this anywhere, so I decided to get creative, and check the Korean subtitles when Karum speaks, and as luck would have it, it WORKED!

At approx 1hr 20mins in, we have a scene where Karum is offcamera and speaks these words in the English dub:

> Since when am I in charge of the money?

And the Korean subtitles give this (via Google translate):

> in pidgin, nigeria

> Have I been in charge of money ever since?

[image: Karum with Subtitles]

Comment: Nice detective work! I think I was watching the original Korean version.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not an expert on this specific language, to me it sounds very much like Patwa, a creole of Jamaica with largely English based vocabulary that could arguably be considered (in my opinion MISTAKEN for) an English dialect, which is perhaps how it was missed in the IMDB credits, but really ought to be listed as it's own language considering how unintelligible it is to most standard English speakers outside of Jamaica. Most Jamaican kids grow up speaking Patwa and don't learn English until they're in school.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamaican_Patois

Answer (score -1):

Karum speaks Nigerian Pidgin English in Space Sweepers. It most definitely isn't Jamaican Patois. Not even close.

Comment: Care to explain how YOU know the answer so emphatically?